# GPIO.add_event_detect fires callback multiple times and on wrong signal edge

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I'm trying to make an interrupt based matrix keypad reader that is loosely based off of [this library](http://crumpspot.blogspot.com/p/keypad-matrix-python-package.html). However, I'm getting some really weird effects when trying to use GPIO.add_event_detect in that:

- Despite wanting the falling edge, I get the rising edge as well
- In some cases, the callback continues to fire until I release the key. Weirdly, this seems to only happen on column 3 (GPIO #22) and not the others, usually.

In my code, I'm removing the callback events as soon as I enter the callback because I have to switch the columns that were inputs with callbacks to outputs so that I can read the rows and determine the key that was pressed. It *always* figures out the correct key, it's just that it either fires off continuously and/or gets another call back on the rising edge (key released)... I've accommodated for the rising edge issue in code but I don't get why it should happen in the first place.

Code below, please excuse my many debug print statements:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class keypad():
    def __init__(self):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

        # CONSTANTS 
        self.KEYPAD = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9],
            ["*",0,"#"]
        ]

        self.ROW         = [18,23,24,25]
        self.COLUMN      = [4,17,22]

        self.__setInterruptMode()

    def __colRise(self, channel):
        print ""
        print "Chan: " + str(channel)
        print "State: " + str(GPIO.input(channel))
        if GPIO.input(channel) > 0:
            return

        #remove interrupt temporarily
        #GPIO.remove_event_detect(channel)
        for c in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            print "Remove: " + str(self.COLUMN[c])
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(self.COLUMN[c])

        #get column number
        colVal = -1
        for c in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            if channel == self.COLUMN[c]:
                colVal = c

        print "ColVal: " + str(colVal)

        if colVal >=0 and colVal < len(self.COLUMN):

            #set rows as intputs
            for r in range(len(self.ROW)):
                GPIO.setup(self.ROW[r], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

            #set triggered column as output
            GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(channel, GPIO.LOW)

            # Scan rows for pushed key/button
            rowVal = -1
            for r in range(len(self.ROW)):
                tmpRead = GPIO.input(self.ROW[r])
                if tmpRead == 0:
                    rowVal = r

            print "RowVal: " + str(rowVal)
            if rowVal >= 0 and rowVal <= 3:
                print str(self.KEYPAD[rowVal][colVal])
            else:
                print "Invalid Row!"
        else:
            print "Invalid Col!"

        #re-enable interrupts
        self.__setInterruptMode()

    def __setInterruptMode(self):
        #set the first row as output low
        #only first one needed as it will ground to all columns
        for r in range(len(self.ROW)):
            GPIO.setup(self.ROW[r], GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(self.ROW[r], GPIO.LOW)

        #set columns as inputs and attach interrupt handlers on rising edge
        for c in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            GPIO.setup(self.COLUMN[c], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
            GPIO.add_event_detect(self.COLUMN[c], GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=500, callback=self.__colRise)


    def cleanup(self):
        GPIO.cleanup()
        print "Cleanup done!"

import time     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    key = keypad()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        key.cleanup()
```

Comment: I have noticed my hardware sortof works like an antenna also. I dont know what your hardware looks like, but raising the high voltage or lowering the low may be worth trying.

Comment: Kinda thought the voltage was fixed at 0V or 3.3V?

Comment: depends on your resistor-usage, can you show us your hardware?

Comment: It's a standard 4x3 matrix keypad hooked directly into the GPIO pins as described in the code. The only resistors in use are the built in pull up/down resistors on the chip, also as described in the code. Not really much else to show.

Comment: ok, I don't know much about the internal resistors and how they influence the 3.3v, and if you maybe would be better off make it a pull-down, instead of pullup circuit. But I'm sure someone else has some better knowledge of this part.

Comment: sadly, I've tried it with both already

Comment: The problem you are having is almost certainly contact bounce. While you have `GPIO.add_event_detect(self.COLUMN[c], GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=500, callback=self.__colRise)` this will only operate on the bounce following press, but not when the key is released. You also need to make sure that the wiring layout minimises interference, as the Pi GPIO is very sensitive to stray signals.

Comment: Ahhh... makes sense. Not sure what I can do about the wiring, it's pretty simple and most of it is in the keypad itself. I wish I could simply ignore any new callback directly after the initial one but it doesn't ALWAYS happen, so it's tough to check for.

Comment: If GPIO 22 is the only one, try using some other GPIO. If it's bounce, you might want to try adding some small capacitors to the inputs. You could also try to have the code trigger rise and fall, and store the current state of the pin in a variable. If the state hasn't changed immediately exit the function (return).

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of this problem before ([How does python GPIO bouncetime parameter work?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14105/how-does-python-gpio-bouncetime-parameter-work)). I think the best solution in the end was to program around the issue, adding code to detect the extra bounces (button presses).